# Flask server static files not loading

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, wsgi

I made a very simple Flask server and a simple index which contains some text and 5 images. The images won't load, I looked at the requests and the file size is very small compared to the actual image size. Altough the responses are around a couple of KB in size part of the images is showing. The server is locally hosted on a device which is connected directly through ethernet to my laptop.

index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

        <title>Test Server</title>

    </head>

    <body>

        <h5> HELLO WORLD!</h5>
        <p>This is the server talking</p>
        <p>I am currently sick but I'll be fine soon :)</p>
        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/a.jpg') }}"></img>
        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/b.jpg') }}"></img>
        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/c.jpg') }}"></img>
        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/d.jpg') }}"></img>
        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/e.jpg') }}"></img>


        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

server.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import gevent
from gevent import monkey

gevent.monkey.patch_all()

from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, copy_current_request_context, redirect, request, session, send_file, make_response, flash
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
import os

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="/test-server/current/src/templates/", \
            static_folder="/test-server/current/src/static", \
            static_url_path="/test-server/current/src/static")

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

app.config.update(
    SECRET_KEY = 'you-will-never-guess',
)
# Index route
@app.route("/")
@app.route('/home')
def index():

    try:
        nothing = ''

    except Exception as err:
        print(str(err))

    finally:

        response = render_template("index.html")
        return response

# Starts the app listening to port 80
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.jinja_env.cache = {}
    app.run(host='192.168.16.1',port=80, threaded=True)
```

And these are the responses I get when I reload the page:

[image]

Comment: `img` element doesn't require closing tag as it is considered an empty element, Look what [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Empty_element) says.

Comment: Ok but that is not the problem here, it will also not load JS scripts, or CSS files. Sometimes after reloading one of the images will fully load and display correctly.

Comment: @RobertŢiganetea are you sure that `images` folder is exists in `static`? just make sure that image by path `/test-server/current/src/static/images/a.jpg` is exists.